# Notification with codeigniter error

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have a problem when i will show number of notification like this 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3Zxb.png)

this is my view nombre.php:

```
<?php
    $CI =& get_instance();

    $CI->load->model("notif_model");

    $notification = new notif_model();

    $notifications = $notification->countNotif();
    echo $notifications;

?>
```

and create a file controller.php in application/core:

```
<?php
    class Controller extends ci_controller{

    static function &get_instance()
    {
        return CI_Controller::get_instance();
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html?highlight=library and https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#class-constructors

Answer (score 1):

Question is bit unclear. However, you are not using framework correct way. Try this way:

In APPPATH.'controllers/Some_controller.php'

```
<?php

class Some_controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model("notif_model");
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data['notifications'] = $this->notif_model->countNotif();
        $this->load->view('some/index', $data);
    }

}
```

In APPPATH.'views/some/index.php'

```
<?php
var_dump($notifications);
```

You have lot of errors that are out of coding scope. Check coding standards that framework requires (I.e. filenames/classnames). [Docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/index.html).